# Different result grep() and "=="

Tags: r, regex, string, match

I have the following dummy data.frame:

```
set.seed(666)
df<-data.frame(ID=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=11),Year=rep(2010:2020,each=1,3),x1=floor(runif(33,0,10)),x2=floor(runif(33,0,2)),
                   x3=floor(runif(33,1,100)),x4=floor(runif(33,1,100)),x5=floor(runif(33,1,100)))
```

I'd like to know how many NAs- either as string "NA" or missing value NA the data.frame contains.
To test I run the following lines:

```
print(length(grep("\\<NA\\>", df)))
print(length(which(is.na(df))))
print(length(which(df=="NA")))
```

Introducing NAs as missing values:

```
df$x1[rbinom(33,1,0.1)==1]<-"NA"
df$x2[rbinom(33,1,0.1)==1]<-NA
df$x3[rbinom(33,1,0.1)==1]<-NA
df$x4[rbinom(33,1,0.1)==1]<-NA
df$x5[rbinom(33,1,0.1)==1]<-NA
```

The results of the same lines as above differ from 2 to 5. Is.na() works fine for the missing values. But the string-match seems to be off as you can see below:

```
print(length(grep("\\<NA\\>", df)))
print(length(which(is.na(df))))
print(length(which(df=="NA")))
```

I'd expect grep() and "==" to return the same answer when looking for the string "NA", but they differ greatly and i don't know why. And which one is the better? I noticed for larger data.frames(2.000.000x 30 ) grep() takes very long. Any faster options?

Thanks.A.Lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to being slower, `print(length(grep("\\<NA\\>", df)))` doesn't give the result you're looking for. It gives not the number of cells that match, but rather the number of columns that, when converted to type: character, match `\<NA\>`.

So

```
print(length(which(df=="NA")))
```

is definitely better.

Addendum: as @Onyambu points out in a bellow comment, it's simpler to use sum instead of print length which. This gives the total number of cells that are NA or "NA", e.g.,

```
sum(is.na(df))
sum(df=="NA")
# total:
sum(is.na(df)|df=="NA")
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought grep() would return a vector for each column containing True and false. But i just wont use it for this task.

Comment: just use `sum(is.na(df))`